# iOS UITableViewCell title slides completely out of view when editing

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

I have a simple `UITableView`

[image]

I'm doing my first *Edit* implementation, to add *Delete* functionality. Most of this stuff is the default apparently. Pretty much the only method I added to my `Controller` is

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Program *victim = Site.current.sortedPrograms[indexPath.row];
    [Site.current removeProgram: victim];
    [self.tableView
        deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: @[indexPath]
        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

When I hit the *Edit* button, I see

[image]

which is good. But When I hit the *minus* button on one with a shorter title, I see the following

[image]

The title is completely scrolled out of site! Similarly, if I use the iOS 7 *swipe left* gesture, even on a longer title, the title is scrolled out of view:

[image]

The code I use to create the cell is pretty simple:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProgramCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Program *program = Site.current.sortedPrograms[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = program.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [program.script prettyCycleDuration];
    return cell;
}
```

This isn't what I want my users to see. I would rather see it scroll the title only if necessary, so that context (not whitespace) associates with the delete button. I am just using a stock `UITableViewCell` (not a subclass), and I'm setting the 'style' to *Subtitle*. I've looked at the delegate methods, and a book I have, but I don't see anything that shows how to deal with this. Is there a way? Will I need to do my own Cell subclass and handle the states more explicitly? Or is there something else I can do?

**Update**
Even after converting to a custom subclass, with constraint based layouts for my cell, it still slides the whole view over, rather than *compress* it.

Comment: Sadly this is Apple's idea of a good UI. I filed a bug on this issue back during the iOS 7 beta.

Comment: I'm I right in guessing that with a custom subclass and some extra work, I can get something better?

Comment: I have done this a bunch of times and never encountered a problem. The only thing I needed to know was that you must add any views to cell.contentView not cell. Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: @user2891327 Updated to include that.

Comment: The issue isn't in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Strange. Try this before returning cell.     [cell.textLabel removeFromSuperview];
    [cell.detailTextLabel removeFromSuperview];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.textLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.detailTextLabel];

Comment: No difference @user2891327